# Get code field in oauth method

Tags: oauth, slack-api, slack

I try to authenticate Slack. I will use, oauth, if I can. 
How can I get the `code` field which is required for `oauth.access`?

https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.access

To be able to test the method, I should fill;

```
client_id       Required    
client_secret   Required    
code            Required    
redirect_uri    Optional
```

Alright I get client_id and client_secret from `OAuth Information`. But where should I get the code field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps of negotiating tokens with OAuth are sequential -- it's not possible to test all of the OAuth API methods in the tester alone, as part of the sequence of events is your server receiving a callback containing that `token` value you'll need for the `oauth.access` step.

The [OAuth documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) lays out the steps in order and is probably a better overall reference than the method documentation alone.